# Is it possible change ARInvoice Project/Conract search field description?

Tags: acumatica

On the Acumatica Invoice page in the Project/Conract search field by default search result show in format: "ProjectID - ProjectDescription". May be somebody know - Can we change this to "ProjectID - CustomerName"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi58R.png)

Answer (score 0):

The ProjectID field uses the attribute ActiveProjectOrContractBaseAttribute.  So I created a an extension which assigns the Description field.  Override the default attribute in ProjectID field with this custom attribute.  See if this achieves your goal.

```
public class ActiveProjectOrContractBaseAttributeExtended : AcctSubAttribute, IPXFieldVerifyingSubscriber
{
    protected Type customerField;

    public ActiveProjectOrContractBaseAttributeExtended() : this(null) { }

    public ActiveProjectOrContractBaseAttributeExtended(Type customerField)
    {
        this.customerField = customerField;

        PXDimensionSelectorAttribute select;

        if (PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.projectModule>() && customerField != null)
        {

            List<Type> command = new List<Type>();

            command.AddRange(new[] {
            typeof(Search2<,,>),
                typeof(PMProject.contractID),
                typeof(LeftJoin<,>),
                        typeof(Customer),
                        typeof(On<,>),
                        typeof(Customer.bAccountID),
                        typeof(Equal<>),
                        typeof(PMProject.customerID),
                    });

            command.AddRange(
                new[]
                {

                    typeof(Where<,,>),
                    typeof (PMProject.nonProject),
                    typeof (Equal<>),
                    typeof (True),
                    typeof (Or2<,>),
                    typeof (Where2<,>),
                    typeof (Where<,,>),
                    typeof (PMProject.customerID),
                    typeof (Equal<>),
                    typeof (Current<>),
                    customerField,
                    typeof (And<,,>),
                    typeof (PMProject.restrictProjectSelect),
                    typeof (Equal<>),
                    typeof (PMRestrictOption.customerProjects),
                    typeof (Or<,,>),
                    typeof (PMProject.restrictProjectSelect),
                    typeof (Equal<>),
                    typeof (PMRestrictOption.allProjects),
                    typeof (Or<,>),
                    typeof(PMProject.baseType),
                    typeof(Equal<PX.Objects.CT.CTPRType.contract>),
                    typeof (Or<,>),
                    typeof (Current<>),
                    customerField,
                    typeof (IsNull),
                    typeof (And2<,>),
                    typeof (Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>),
                    typeof (Or<,>),
                    typeof (PMProject.nonProject),
                    typeof (Equal<>),
                    typeof (True)
                });

            select = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(ProjectAttribute.DimensionName,
            BqlCommand.Compose(command.ToArray())
            , typeof(PMProject.contractCD), typeof(PMProject.contractCD), typeof(PMProject.description),
             typeof(PMProject.status), typeof(PMProject.customerID), typeof(Customer.acctName), typeof(PMProject.curyID));
        }
        else
        {
            select = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(ProjectAttribute.DimensionName,
            typeof(Search2<PMProject.contractID,
            LeftJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<PMProject.customerID>>>,
            Where<PMProject.nonProject, Equal<True>, Or<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>)
            , typeof(PMProject.contractCD), typeof(PMProject.contractCD), typeof(PMProject.description),
            typeof(PMProject.status), typeof(PMProject.customerID), typeof(Customer.acctName), typeof(PMProject.curyID) 
            );
        }

        select.DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName);
        select.ValidComboRequired = true;
        select.CacheGlobal = true;

        _Attributes.Add(select);
        _SelAttrIndex = _Attributes.Count - 1;

        Filterable = true;
        DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName);
    }

    public virtual void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        PMProject project = PXSelect<PMProject>.Search<PMProject.contractID>(sender.Graph, e.NewValue);
        if (customerField != null && project != null && project.NonProject != true)
        {
            int? customerID = (int?)sender.GetValue(e.Row, customerField.Name);

            if (customerID != project.CustomerID)
            {
                sender.RaiseExceptionHandling(FieldName, e.Row, e.NewValue,
                    new PXSetPropertyException(Warnings.ProjectCustomerDontMatchTheDocument, PXErrorLevel.Warning));
            }
        }
    }
}
```